# Причастия — всегда ли однородные определения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, причастия, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Всегда ли причастия являются однородныии определениями? Вообще, конкретно такого правила я не находил ни в одном из справочников, но, в принципе, особо не встречал случаев, где ряд причастий не разделяется запятыми. Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить эту ситуацию!

Comment: Интересный вопрос у вас Игорь, но требует к себе чуть больше времени. Здесь важно обозначить ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЕ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ  для однородных и неоднородных отношений между причастиями.

Answer (score 5):

Отдельного такого правила и не надо, достаточно одного - об однородных и  неоднородных определениях, а уж чем они выражены - смотрите сами. Чаще всего причастия соседствуют с прилагательными. Целый ряд одиночных причастий, думаю, будет нечитабельным. Неоднородные определения, выраженные одиночными
причастиями, встречаются, но я бы тоже назвала их "корявыми". Вот, например:

Начинавшаяся завывающая метель его остановила.

Я подошёл к скулящему промокшему  комочку.

Поднимающееся пузырящееся тесто; завывающий усиливающийся  ветер;
разбросанные изрешечённые игрушки; качающийся подмороженный цветок.

Полученное измятое письмо он засунул в карман.

Летящий  крутящийся  шар  привлёк  внимание.